# Unity3d Collision not detected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I have a problem with an object "lightsaber", so may object is like this

[image]

Saber is child of lightsaber.

From Lightsabermanager I active the components of parent and child but using a Rigidbody Unity doesn't "draw" the line render, and using or not Rigidbody the method below doen't work

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    Debug.Log(col.gameObject.tag);
}
```

Comment: Both colliding objects must have a collider (aside from one having also the rigidbody). From the pick your right one has a collider, but it is not active. If the two there shall collide, both need a collider.

Comment: When the lightsaber is off all components are not active, but when it's on all components have a flag but not working

Comment: And the other object does have a collider too?

Comment: Do you mean the other objects as enemies?

Comment: Yes, those that you want to hit.

Comment: Yes they have colliders.